# Ember template doesn't update after model update

Tags: ember.js, model

http://jsbin.com/qoyudape/1/edit

Despite using `.pushObject()` template doesn't update. I've noticed it DOES update, if instead `this` I use `model` or `content` in template;

What is `this` in view is referring to if not model ? Is it possible to get it working using `this` and not `model` or `content` ?

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return Ember.A();
  }
});

App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    update: function(){
      this.get("model").pushObject( Ember.Object.create({a:"b"}) );
      console.log( this.get("model") );
    }
  }
});
```

template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">

    <button {{action "update"}}>update</button>
    <br><br>

    {{#if this}}
      array not empty
    {{else}}
      array empty
    {{/if}}
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is referring to the controller.  btw, an easy way to find that out is to do `{{log this}}` in your template see also: http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/debugging/.

I'm not actually sure what it's checking to be truthy/falsy, but you can always just use length.  I'll update once I find it.

```
{{#if this.length}}
  array not empty
{{else}}
  array empty
{{/if}}
```

http://jsbin.com/qoyudape/3/edit

Comment: But why is it working on initial load, but doesn't work on update ?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's technically working, I think it might be observing something else on the collection and finding it falsy.